# Storybook React and their example component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm currently following this: https://storybook.js.org/basics/writing-stories/

And I created an example component button:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = props => {
    return (
        <button>
           Hello
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

However, I'm not exactly sure what is going on under the hood in Storybook that this ends up creating the stories in the left navigation area, but the story examples that get rendered in my build are in fact my default Hello button.

Comment: What’s the issue you are facing? What are you expecting from us?

Comment: @Think-Twice the buttons in both stories show up simply saying "Hello" (from the original button component that is imported in the /stories/index.js (see the code on https://storybook.js.org/basics/writing-stories/). It should have one with basic text and another with emojis. I'm not sure what I'm expected to have in the original button component that is being imported.

Comment: Can you show us your button.stories.js file

Answer (score 0):

Are you mentioning, that when you fire up storybook, you just see your button with “hello” text and not any of the prop value that you are passing into it?

If so, you must use the prop within the button definition as mentioned in the above answer.

If its some other issue, please provide more info on it.

Answer (score -4):

First of all That's not how you use props.

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = () => {
    return (
        <button>
           Hello
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

This will work. And if you wanna use props do like this.

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <button>
           {this.props.yourPropName}     
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

`this.props.yourPropName` will show what you send using props.

Comment: He didn't wrap props in parenthesis.

Comment: @Manish Pant Parenthesis isn’t required for single param

Comment: I don't think theres anything wrong with that way of formatting props in an arrow function with a single parameter. Also, the question isn't really primarily about React, it is about using Storybook (see link in the original post).

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Manish. However, that doesn't resolve the actual issue with Storybook. Storybook is a UI development framework. The question is not about how to use props.